# How to add security to UPDATE / DELETING a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, I'm trying to add a security feature which basically makes it so that only a person that owns a certain task can modify it. So if some random guy came, and tried to modify that task, they would not be able to.

Here is the MY updateOne() function that updates a document:

```
exports.updateOne = (Model) => {
  return catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const document = await Model.findById(req.params.id);
    const name = Model.modelName.toLowerCase();
    console.log(name, req.user.id, document.user);

    if (!document) {
      return next(new AppError(`Could not find ${name}`, 404));
    }

    // SECURITY

    // if document is a task, check if current user owns the task
    if (name === "task" && `${req.user.id}` !== `${document.user}`) {
      return next(new AppError("You do not own this task!", 401));
    }

    await document.updateOne(req.body, {
      new: true,
    });

    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        [name]: document,
      },
    });
  });
};
```

The problem here is that it works completely fine, it checks if the modelName is a task, and also if the currently logged in user (req.user) is the same as the user that owns the task but it cannot display the updated result. I tried researching, and they said document.updateOne() cannot use "new" in it's options, meaning the updated document is not shown in the request. So what I would like, is a fix, or a complete differentway of doing it.

HEADS UP:
AppError is my own error handling thingy, so just think of it as something that throws an error to the user's response

catchAsync is a function that catches the errors and stuff

This is also in a function that auto sends the CRUD responses, so that's why theres a weird return stuff.

Comment: Why don't you use `findByIdAndUpdate`? It allows you to return the newly updated document.

Comment: because if I do it like that, the document already updated. Unless theres a way I can cancel an update I'm not sure I can use it liek that

Comment: Why do you want to cancel the update? You already checked if the logged in user is the same user who created the document.

Comment: My log in does not check if the user created the document, it only checks if the user is logged in

Comment: What does this line do ` if (name === "task" && `${req.user.id}` !== `${document.user}`) {
      return next(new AppError("You do not own this task!", 401));
    }`

Comment: name === "task" checks if the document is a task, so this security wouldnt happen on another document like a user

${req.user.id} !== ${document.user} checks if the task owner's id is the same as the logged in user (req.user)

Comment: `${req.user.id} !== ${document.user} checks if the task owner's id is the same as the logged in user (req.user)` So, you check if the logged in user is the creator of the document. If the user is not the creator, then an error is thrown as per your code. If the code continues, then it must be that the logged in user is the same as the creator of the document. Am I missing something?

Comment: yeah, so that part works, but the thing is, even though it sends an error to the client, the document still gets updated

Comment: Convert both ids in the if statement to string using the `.toString()` method.

Comment: I already did that with the ``